# Oracle SQL Developer User-Defined Formatting Rules

Tags: coding-style, oracle-sqldeveloper, autoformatting

I am currently defining the auto-formatting rules for our company. For Toad I already did it, but now the challenge is, to define them for the SQL developer. Since the SQL Developer does not offer that many options as the TOAD I have to use the user-defined ones.

My questions:

- Is there maybe a good way to convert the TOAD rules to SQL developer rules?
- Do you know whether there is a documentation about the syntax of the user-defined rules? Google does not lead to any good results, and also just following the wordpress link that is provided in the default ones did not help that much.

Really looking forward to your help.

The wordpress link I was talking about:
https://vadimtropashko.wordpress.com/2017/01/03/custom-formatting-in-sqldev-4-2/